# Show NSError as a message

Tags: ios, swift, nserror

How can I show a error as a normal message:

I have a signin function:

```
func signIn() {
        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(self.usernameTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!) {
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if user != nil {
                // Do stuff after successful login.
                print("User successfully logged in: \(user)")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: nil)
            } else {
                // The login failed. Check error to see why.
                print("Server reported an error: \(error)")

                // create the alert
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "\(error)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                // add an action (button)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

                // show the alert
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

And the UIAlertController shows this to the user:

[image]

But how can I only show message as:

> Invalid username/password.

I tried using error.message, but thats not a command, and error.description does not work either.. Any suggestions?

Comment: in that case just show the `localisedDescription` only....

Comment: I have not read the answers... I read the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `localizedDescription`.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "\(error.localizedDescription)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
```

Or get the value for the "error" key from the error's `userInfo` dictionary.

Comment: How do i get rid of the optional? I get this message now: Optional("Invalid username/password.")

Comment: Try `error!.localizeDescription` but that's dangerous because your app will crash if `error` is `nil`.

Comment: I did used that, but still get the "Optional" text in the error message. But if it's dangerous, what other options do i have?

Comment: I don't know Swift so I don't know how to handle all of that crazy optional nonsense (I thought Swift was supposed to be easier - ha!).

Comment: Oh haha ok! I guess i can just use error?.localizeDescription for now.

Comment: In this case the best would probably be a combination of optional binding and nil coercing, e.g. `error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error"`.

Comment: What Sulthan said.

Answer (score 2):

The localized message is in the [`localizedDescription` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSError/localizedDescription):

```
error.localizedDescription
```

Answer (score 2):

Just write

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error!.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
```

As the error is always non-`nil` if the user is `nil`, you can safely unwrap it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try below code using the `optional binding` and `nil coalescing operator`

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "\( error?.localizedDescription ?? " unknown error " )", preferredStyle: .Alert)
```